# Excel Filter works badly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Helo Everyone,
I have a problem with filter, please help me.
I used filters before and everything was ok.
Today, I imported data from a text file. After importing data, I used a filter as in the attachment and rows don't meet criteria still appear.
Can you help me?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the filter was not applied to the whole range of cells.  Since there is a line there that appears to be all blank (row 211), the filter may have stopped at that spot instead of covering all the data.

If you select all the cells (really columns `A:C`) and apply the filter again, it should probably work.